# Who is Amanda Von Doom?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In the new ongoing The Incredible Hulk, a woman named Amanda Von Doom recruits the Hulk's help in tracking down Bruce Banner (they've been split up [again]), because Banner is creating additional animal Hulks in an attempt to re-Hulk himself. Her team (the Mad Squad, a super-double-hyper-incredibly secret don't talk about it seriously government team) is tasked with taking down "mad scientists," and Banner apparently meets the criteria now.

Numerous times she states "no relation" (reference Victor Von Doom, I assume), but that may not be honest given

> Doom's involvement in separating the Hulk and Bruce Banner.

Has Amanda Von Doom been seen anywhere else? Might she actually be related (i.e. has Dr. Doom had any children)? Who in the world is this lady?

[image: Amanda Von Doom]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amanda von Doom first appeared in Incredible Hulk (volume 3) issue #1 in October 2011.  This was her first appearance in the Marvel Universe according to the [Comic Book Database](http://comicbookdb.com/character_chron.php?ID=58558) the [Marvel wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_3_1) and the [Grand Comics Database.](http://www.comics.org/issue/888732/)

She has not appeared anywhere other than the Incredible Hulk (vol. 3) issues 1-5.
Anything online about who she is or where she comes from outside of what was shown in those issues is speculation only.

According to [Marvel](http://marvel.com/universe/Doctor_Doom_%28Victor_von_Doom%29) Doom has only two known relatives.  His father Werner von Doom and his mother Cynthia von Doom both of whom are deceased.